# What is this odd box?

Tags: support

I was going through the review queue and saw this box under the comments. What is it and where did it come from? I also check the question page itself and it's there, too, in the same position under that answer's comments.

[image: orange texted box]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "post notice". Post notices are available to diamond moderators on both questions and answers:

[image]

Their usefulness tends to vary a lot by site, and I personally find their use on answers to be likely ineffective. But on questions, the "insufficient explanation" post notice in particular can guide folks to post better answers if the question is otherwise attracting quick answers that lack in detail or insights.

Comment: I think the insufficient explanation one could be used in parallel (or in lieu of) protecting questions such as [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135560/clothing-store-access-in-pokemon-x-y), especially if said question is garnering a lot of views quickly (and a lot of speculative answers).